# WCF bindingnamespace inconsistent between environments

Tags: wcf, namespaces

I'm at the client end of a wcf service. I've promoted my code from the test environment to live. My live test failed. The service provided says I need to change the bindingNamespace. However as i'm at the client end so I can't set the bindingNamespace in the client endpoint's config file, can I? Also am i correct in thinking that the serivice provider shouldn't be changing the bindingNamespace between dev, test and live environments. Surely that's what the address is for?

endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="https://www.abc123LIVE.co.uk/foo/webservices/operations"

endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="https://www.acb123TEST.co.uk/foo/webservices/operations"